# Do beaches / beach resorts in Cebu employ lifeguards?

Tags: safety, beaches, philippines

Me and my friend are planning to go swimming in an exclusive resort or stay in a beachfront hotel within Cebu as long as the beach is perfect. But unfortunately none of us know how to swim well but we really love swimming in the beach. Do all  beaches in Cebu have lifeguards just in case of drowning? Or do they look out for their guests? Just for us not to feel worry.

Comment: The one time I've stayed at a resort with a private beach in Cebu I don't recall any lifeguards on the beach -- it's pretty big. There's people on [tripadvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.com.ph/ShowUserReviews-g298461-d306050-r174229876-Shangri_La_s_Mactan_Resort_Spa-Lapu_Lapu_Mactan_Island_Cebu_Island_Visayas.html) complaining about lifeguards at the *pool*. It'll depend a lot on the hotel I think.

Comment: I updated the title of the question, because "safe" is a bit too generic (you could be talking about things like crime).

Answer (score 5):

I've never seen any lifeguards at any of the beaches I've been to in Cebu. I'm not a good swimmer either and haven't had any problems at the beaches in Cebu.

In general, I found that the waves and water are calm. Because the waves are so calm, it's quite easy to swim in the water. Likewise, some beaches have very shallow water so you will need to go out quite far in order to go into the deep end. My advice is to go to the beaches that have calm water, and you will be fine.

Comment: If beaches are long and shallow, it might be important to be aware of tides and rip currents. Any info on these/the lack of these?

Answer (score 1):

Most beaches don't have lifeguards but they have personnel who will watch the beach/pool sometimes. Exclusive resorts/beaches has designated lifeguards. It's a requirement. But there's no need to worry if you'll just abide with the rules & regulation printed on a large signboard near the beach.